# Adicionar Contatos em uma Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

Gostaria de adicionar contatos em uma `ArrayList`, porem adicionando valores iniciais ao atributo.

Primeiramente criei uma classe Chamada contato , e quero criar uma ArrayList do tipo contato e gostaria de saber como adicionar dados a este  ArrayList

Esta é a classe contato :

```
public class Contato implements  ModeloContato {
    // ATRIBUTOS
    private String nome;
    private int telefone;
    private String endereco;



    //METODODOS ESPECIAIS 

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(int telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }



    //METODOS DA INTERFACE
    @Override
    public void getnome() {

    }

    @Override
    public void gettelefone() {

    }

    @Override
    public void getendereco() {

    }



}
```

este é o main :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Contato> agenda = new ArrayList<Contato>();

    Contato a = new Contato ();
    Contato b = new Contato ();
    Contato c = new Contato ();
```

Comment: Tentou criar um método `adicionarContato` como expliquei? Não vi essa tentativa no código.

Comment: Por que os métodos getters de nome, telefone e endereço estão repetidos? Que interface é essa? Não faz sentido você implementar uma interface e não utilizar nada dele, e ainda criar métodos com assinaturas semelhantes dessa forma.

Comment: Também fiquei em duvida a respeito Disso @Articuno , porem foi o que foi pedido no exercício .

Comment: Onde devo colocar o AdicionarContato ? no método main ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para atribuir valores no ato de criação de um objeto nós criamos um construtor, a sintaxe é a seguite:

```
public class MinhaClasse{

    // Tem o mesmo nome da classe só que sem o class
    public MinhaClasse(){

    }
}
```

*Obs.: Um objeto pode ter mais de um construtor, desde que os parâmetros sejam diferentes.*

Quanto ao fato de usar uma interface (e também por ser um exercício) acredito que era para dizer quais métodos sua classe obrigatoriamente teria que ter, quando eles não existem o compilador pede que você os implemente. (Como você não postou o código da interface isso é uma suposição)

No seu caso o construtor ficaria assim:

```
public class Contato implements  ModeloContato {
    // ATRIBUTOS
    private String nome;
    private int telefone;
    private String endereco;

    public Contato(String nome, int telefone, String endereco){
        // o this serve pra indicar que estamos tratando do atributo da classe.
        // Ele é usado quando o nome da variável local é igual ao nome do atributo
        this.nome = nome;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    // [...] Getters e setters
 }
```

Para adicioná-los no seu ArrayList use o método add ou Collections.addAll() dessa forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<Contato> agenda = new ArrayList<Contato>();

     Contato a = new Contato ("Contato1",123456,"Endereço1");
     Contato b = new Contato ("Contato2",123456,"Endereço2");
     Contato c = new Contato ("Contato3",123456,"Endereço3");

     // Método tradicional
     agenda.add(a);
     agenda.add(b);
     agenda.add(c);

     // Método sem paciência
     //Collections.addAll(agenda,a,b,c);
}
```